# Unable to send file from source folder to directory [python]

Tags: python, file, directory, copy, shutil

I am using `shutil.copy` to send a file to an intended folder within a directory, based on the file's file name.

I have the following list of files in a folder called "Downloaded_Data":

```
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_2.csv
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_3.csv  
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_A_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_A_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Mild_D_C_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_A_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_A_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Blue_Hot_D_C_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_A_2.csv
Subject_Red_Cold_D_A_3.csv  
Subject_Red_Cold_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Cold_D_C_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_A_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_A_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_A_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_B_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_B_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_B_3.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_C_1.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_C_2.csv 
Subject_Red_Hot_D_C_3.csv
```

I then need to sort all of these files into their intended sub-folder within a folder called "Input_Data. And so I need to place these files into the following file directory based on their file names:

```
Input_Data > Blue_Cold
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
           > Blue_Mild
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
           > Blue_Hot
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
           > Red_Cold
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
           > Red_Mild
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
           > Red_Hot
                > DA
                > DB
                > DC
```

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
import os

source_folder = os.path.join("Downloaded_Data")

for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):

    name_parts = filename.split("_")
    
    first_folder = "_".join([name_parts[1], name_parts[2]])
    
    second_folder = "D" + name_parts[4]

    dest_root_dir = Path('Input_Data')
    dest_dir = dest_root_dir.joinpath(first_folder, second_folder, filename)
    dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    dest_filepath = dest_dir.joinpath(filename)
    shutil.copy2(filename, dest_dir)
```

And I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-257fc6665649> in <module>()
     29     dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
     30     dest_filepath = dest_dir.joinpath(filename)
---> 31     shutil.copy2(filename, dest_dir)
     32 
     33 

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copy2(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    255     if os.path.isdir(dst):
    256         dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
--> 257     copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    258     copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    259     return dst

~\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    118         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    119     else:
--> 120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_1.csv .csv'
```

Why am I receiving this error if this file exists and is previously recognized by the code? How can I fix this so that these files will end up in the correct folder?

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` returns just the base file names, without their path names. You should prepend the file names with path names when you perform any operations based on the file names:

```
shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), dest_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution.

```sh
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def custom_copy(series: Path, source_path: Path):
    source = source_path.joinpath(series.name)
    series.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
    shutil.copy2(source, series.parent)
    
    
source_path = Path("./Downloaded_Data/")
target_path = Path("./Input_Data/")

# file_pattern: extract info from file name.
# group a: (?P<a>[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)                                             -> Red_Mild
# group b: (?P<b>[A-Z]_[A-Z])                                                     -> D_A
# group c: (?P<c>[a-zA-Z]+_(?P<a>[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)_(?P<b>[A-Z]_[A-Z])_\d\.csv) -> Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_1.csv
file_pattern = r"(?P<c>[a-zA-Z]+_(?P<a>[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)_(?P<b>[A-Z]_[A-Z])_\d\.csv)"

_ = (
    pd.Series(source_path.glob("Subject_*.csv"))                  # 1. get all files from the source folder.
    .apply(lambda x: x.name)                                      # 2. extract filenames form files.
    .str.extract(file_pattern)                                    # 3. extract file patterns from filenames.
    .assign(b=lambda x: x.b.str.replace("_", ""))                 # 4. D_A -> DA: can be simplified
    .sort_index(axis=1)                                           # 5. sort groups to a-b-c.
    .apply(lambda x: target_path.joinpath(*x.values), axis=1)     # 6. construct target file path.
    .apply(custom_copy, source_path=source_path)                  # 7. execute the copy command.
)
```

And the result is:

```
$ tree Input_Data 
Input_Data
├── Blue_Cold
│   ├── DA
│   │   ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_1.csv
│   │   ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_2.csv
│   │   └── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_A_3.csv
│   ├── DB
│   │   ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_1.csv
│   │   ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_2.csv
│   │   └── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_B_3.csv
│   └── DC
│       ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_1.csv
│       ├── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_2.csv
│       └── Subject_Blue_Cold_D_C_3.csv
└── Red_Mild
    ├── DA
    │   ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_1.csv
    │   ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_2.csv
    │   └── Subject_Red_Mild_D_A_3.csv
    ├── DB
    │   ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_1.csv
    │   ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_2.csv
    │   └── Subject_Red_Mild_D_B_3.csv
    └── DC
        ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_1.csv
        ├── Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_2.csv
        └── Subject_Red_Mild_D_C_3.csv
```